# EF RollBack DB context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have an `asp.net mvc` application where the Client wants a `"SAVE"` button. Currently, the way the app works is that per request a new `DBContext` is created and save changes is called. The issue I have is that when I implement the save button

> how can I keep the current implementation of creating a new `DBContext` per request and give the user an option to rollback their changes after a call to `SaveChanges()`?

also, I don't like having the idea of a "Save" button are there any other alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean "give the user an option to rollback their changes"? With the transactional nature of web requests, you're going to make a new request, possibly hitting a different web server, if they hit an "undo" button.

Comment: Do you keep a record of what changed between saves?

Comment: @Krillgar That's why I am asking the question, I want to know if their is a way around that.

Comment: What is the use case for needing to roll back? How soon after saving? This might help us guide you towards the best solution.

Comment: @leemac People are making mistakes left and right and the don't want it saved unless someone is sure what they have done is correct. Essentially the time between the rollback and the save is the X amount of time between the last 2 saves.

Comment: @Michael No not yet.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense understood. I'm currently working on a similar issue at my workplace...we have a staging area for external users where the data they input is stored. Those changes can later be approved and saved back to the original table by authorized users/reviewers. Authorized users can also choose to have them auto-merged as well by a backend service.

Comment: @leemac Thanks, this might be something I would have to implement.

Comment: " People are making mistakes left and right and the don't want it saved unless someone is sure what they have done is correct." are you asking that after the input of a person .they must be sort of a standby phase where someone does validation and verification before it is saved?

Comment: @JephrenNaicker Sorry, "Someone" refers to the person who made the changes, not another person who validates the changes. Yes, it's after the input. I can't validate the data it's sort of like dynamic scheduling going on.

Comment: Sounds more like you need to implement some sort of validation. "Making mistakes" is very broad, and depending on what you mean by that can determine several of dozens of different possible answers.